# c++/cli wrapper for polymorphic native classes

Tags: c++, casting, c++-cli, polymorphism, wrapper

We are writing a c++/cli wrapper for native code that is polymorphic and would like to extend the polymorphism into the non-native side as much as possible. So far, given a c++/cli class instance it is easy to retrieve the underlying native class but the trouble comes when trying to determine which c++/cli wrapper to use for a given native class instance. It would be nice to be able to avoid a switch statement here, but how? Is there a more elegant object-oriented solution?

Note that in the following code I use a prefix of M for C++/CLI types (e.g. FresnelScatterer is a native class and MFresnelScatterer is the C++/CLI wrapper class for it).

The native c++ base class and inherited class:

```
class Scatterer
{
public:
    ScatterType Type;

Scatterer() {}
virtual ~Scatterer() {}

ScatterType GetType() { return Type; }
    // Some virtual functions here...
};
class FresnelScatterer : public Scatterer
{
public:
// virtual function overrides
};
```

The c++/cli base class and inherited class:

```
public ref class MScatterer abstract
{
public:
Scatterer* m_Scatterer;

MScatterer() {}

MScatterer(MScatterer% mscatter)
{
    m_Scatterer = mscatter.m_Scatterer;
}

MScatterer(Scatterer* scatter)
{
    m_Scatterer = scatter;
}

[XmlElement("The_Scatterer_Type")]
int ScattererType;

virtual void initializeXMLdata()
{
    ScattererType = (int) m_Scatterer->GetType();
}

virtual Scatterer* convertXMLdata() = 0;

~MScatterer() { }
// more wrapping here
};

public ref class MFresnelScatterer : MScatterer
{
public:
    MFresnelScatterer() : MScatterer() {}


    MFresnelScatterer(MFresnelScatterer% mfscatter) : MScatterer(mfscatter)
    {
    };

    MFresnelScatterer(FresnelScatterer* mfscatter) : MScatterer(mfscatter)
    {
    };

    virtual void initializeXMLdata() override
    {
        MScatterer::initializeXMLdata();
                    // other init
    }

    virtual Scatterer* convertXMLdata() override
    {
        //Scatterer
        FresnelScatterer* sca = new FresnelScatterer();
        return sca;
    }

};
```

An example where going from C++/CLI -> native C++ works nicely is here:

```
for each ( MScatterer^ mScatterer in readScene->ScattererList)
{
    m_Scene->scattererList.push_back(mScatterer->convertXMLdata());
}
```

But going from native c++, I cannot see how to teach C++/CLI which type my native object is without using a switch statement:

```
for (uint i=0; i<m_Scene->scattererList.size(); i++)
{
    switch (m_Scene->scattererList[i]->GetType())
    {
    case SCA_FRESNEL:
        {
            MFresnelScatterer^ sca = gcnew MFresnelScatterer((FresnelScatterer*) m_Scene->scattererList[i]);
            sca->initializeXMLdata();
            ScattererList->Add(sca);
            break;
        }
    // other cases follow...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may write up a virtual method `CreateObject` in `MScatterer` and implement it in derived classes. The overridden `CreateObject` would create instance of target classes. There is no need to have `GetType` method.

Comment: What should CreateObject() create? A C++/CLI class? This is not possible from within a C++ native class. A C++ native class? Why? You already have one.

Comment: Ok, I think you are suggesting adding `virtual MScatterer^ CreateObject(Scatterer* input) = 0;` to MScatterer and then implementing this in the derived classes like: `virtual MScatterer^ CreateObject(Scatterer* input) override {...}` but how will the program know which derived class to match to the input?

Comment: No. I am suggesting `MScatterer::CreateObject`, whose return type would be MScatterer^ / MScatterer*. There is no need of any argument. Am I missing something?

Comment: I need to create a C++/CLI wrapper of the native object that has the corresponding type. So if I have a native object of type FresnelScatterer, then I want to create a C++/CLI wrapper of type MFresnelScatterer that stores the native pointer. I want this to be general for any derived class of Scatterer.

Comment: I have tried and it is possible to write managed stuff in native class (in `Scatterer`): `MScaterrer^ Create() { return gcnew MScatterrer;}`. You would need to forward declare required class(es).

Comment: I guess that could work in a mix-mode project but I am building the native code into a native dll assembly and importing it, so I cannot use C++/CLI in the native part.

Comment: I cannot give exactly how you can do this, but you can write a wrapper class between unmanaged-managed layer. That would IMO, more of trouble than having a switch statement!